# Is it possible to deactive vibration and ringtone for a call by a certain/specific number?

Tags: calls, ringtone, vibration

I would like to deactivate

1. the ringtone and
2. vibration,

when a certain/specific number is calling me. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible depending on the app you use for calling.

In the AOSP phone app, when you click on a contact, behind the three-dot overflow button there is such an option. I am not aware of a feature to disable vibrations, but as this is handled by your telephony app, you should be able to replace it (by installing a new one and making it default for telephony) with one that supports this feature.

Another option would be to programmatically disable sound and vibrations when a specified number is calling, achievable in a number of different android automation apps (such as Tasker, Automate).

Comment: Not a reply. This content 1. references a new app which is 2. unspecified and thus includes random conditions which makes it all just useless and isn't helping.

Comment: AOSP refers to Android Open Source Project, thus meaning the default phone app on stock android devices without gapps